# CMS for social photo album

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script, photo

I am going to make a multi-user photo album. I am looking for a robust and free CMS which can easily handle batch image uploads and some social networking capabilities, like rating, relationship, etc.

I know that it can be done using Wordpress but I appreciate it if you suggest me to other viable alternatives (not necessarily php-based).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Business Catalyst](http://businesscatalyst.com/) and you can batch upload using FTP. I am not 100% sure what you are looking for but Business Catalyst has some powerful tools that might help you out.

Comment: Thanks but actually I'm looking for something that allows users to batch upload zip files from browser, I want to host it myself and need it to be free :)

Comment: You could use BC for part of that maybe but the free part will get you. Hope you find what you are looking for =>